# Cannot clone from Assembla

Tags: git, netbeans, assembla

I have create git repository. I try to clone using NetBeans. I choose:

Team > Git > Clone
Repository URL: git.assembla.com:myproject.git
Username: git

I select Private/Public
Private Key File: D:\Document\ssh\assembla-private.priv
Passphrase: 1234

When I click Next, There are no list of remote branch. So I cannot select one and click finish.

I am new to Git, so maybe someone can explain what step did I miss

I create ssh key using PuttyGen (private key is exported to OpenSSH)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue,

for anyone else that ends up encountering this issue and is new to git, assembla, netbeans here is a slightly more elaborated guide.

Create a local repository as instructed by assembla, then push the repository. All this can be done on the [msysgit](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?q=net%20installer) client command line.

First things first, create an ssh key by entering :

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Do not enter a name for the key, just press enter. You do not need to create the password either.

Once the keys are created, upload the id_rsa.pub key to assembla. (generally found in username/.ssh/ directory on a windows machine. eg C:\Users\username\.ssh\id_rsa.pub)

In all, the following instructions need to get executed :

```
git config --global user.name "your name" # Set your name
git config --global user.email "your@email" # Set an email
```

Setting the email is important because assembla checks for it. Be sure to provide the one that you registered with.

```
mkdir myproject
cd myproject

git init
touch README
git add README
git commit -m "first commit"

git remote add origin git@git.assembla.com:myproject.git
git push origin master
```

After [Initializing Git in netbeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html) To clone a repository in Netbeans, the following options get me through:

```
Repository URL : git.assembla.com:myproject.git
Username : git

Private Key File : C:\Users\username\\.ssh\id_rsa
```

Hope this helps people like me who are just starting out.

Answer (score 1):

i also had to run this after generating the keys and uploading them to assembla

```
$ ssh-add
```

Comment: This is needed if you deleted id-rsa file which is a certificate you have to import into your local system. without import it, you will get notification error even thou you respected all steps from Assembla instructions.

Answer (score 0):

What do you get when you do:

```
git clone git.assembla.com:myproject.git
```

In a terminal window? I don't know what is Username in netbreans context, but if you are using private/public key authentication assembla shouldn't ask for your username.

Answer (score 0):

When I set up Git in NetBeans, I use `git@git.assembla.com:myproject.git` as the URL and then my Assembla username in the username box.

Use your keys as usual and it should all work fine.

Just curious, do your keys actually have a passphrase - or are you trying to use your Assembla password here? You're probably using your passphrase but I just wanted to double-check.